# How to fill tables in powerpoint from a cell array in matlab?

Tags: matlab, com, powerpoint, cell

I've downloaded saveppt2, jrichter's code and even `WritetoWordfromMatlab` and tried reading through them to figure it out with no luck. I have something of my own built already so I just need to figure out how to get tables to work.

Whenever I try something like:

```
myTable.Cell(1,1).TextFrame.Text = 'textstring'
```

or

```
myTable.Table.Cell(1,1) = 'textstring'
```

Or any combination of table / text commands I end up with there being no such property or function as cell for table objects. Every COM/VBA/C library I can find, as well as some code in Python (PandastoPowerPoint from Github) that does what I'm aiming to do says that Table.Cell(row,col) should work. Is this specifically a problem with matlab trying to use (#,#) as a form of indexing?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 myTable.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "TextString"
```

or = 'TextString' if that's what matlab prefers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve R! With a little tweak, I got it to work, finally. So here's the answer:

% add table to existing slide object

myTable = slide.Shapes.addTable(nRows,nCols,x0,y0,rowWidth*nRows,colHeight*nCols) 
myTable.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = 'TextString'